# Should a comment be left when the question has a drastic edit after answers have been provided?

Tags: feature-request

[In this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/453988/what-are-the-experiments-performed-to-determine-the-position-of-an-electron-insi) is an example where [the editing](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/453988/revisions) by the OP has made a drastic difference and makes nonsense of the answer provided before the edit.

This has happened to me again after edits by moderators and others, but usually I return to look at the questions I answer, to see what others have maybe said,  but this happened during my sleep time.

I think there should be a comment left to the people who answered that the question was edited. We get a comment if our answer is edited, no?

Comment: See Servy's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179215).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if a question is edited in a way that significantly changes what it's asking and invalidates an existing answer, assuming the original version of the question was itself a decent enough question, the edit should be rolled back.

Of course it's a bit of a judgment call whether a given edit significantly changes what the question is asking, but I think this case does meet that bar. So I would suggest undoing the asker's edit in this case. And there's no need for a moderator to do this; anyone with enough reputation can do so. Even the person whose answer was invalidated by the edit to the question can do it, although it might be a good idea to try to get a second opinion because there is the potential for a *slight* conflict of interest there.

If there are many *new* answers that would themselves be invalidated by rolling back the edit, then that might be a reason to make an exception; in that case we'd have to balance the harm done by invalidating the new answers against the good done by revalidating the old answers and maintaining the principle that questions shouldn't be drastically edited. When there's doubt about this, it's probably a good idea to make a meta post, but if the balance is close I'd roll back the edit and write the meta post to ask whether to re-apply it.

> I think there should be a comment left to the people who answered that the question was edited. We get a comment if our answer is edited, no?

No, you do not get a comment left automatically when your answer is edited. The editor may leave you a comment if they think it's necessary, but they have no obligation to do so. However, you do get a *notification* if your answer is edited. It might be reasonable to also get notifications when a question you've answered has been edited, but that could add up to a lot of notifications for some people so there are arguments for an against. This has been [brought up on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer).

Comment: In this case there are two additional answers that do address the edited question. It's not at all clear to me that the correct course of action is to revert the question edit.

Comment: Yeah but the additional answers also address the original question just as well. If that weren't the case, then I would be more hesitant to recommend reverting.

Comment: I've seen a couple of cases where the OP has manually left a comment under old answers saying that the question was badly written, so the answer misses the desired mark (and obviously the question is edited significantly after that). Those usually look like they were made in good faith.